# Missing value in Sparql due to where clause

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have a query which return no records because there isn't a thumbnail in the where clause

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

    SELECT *
    WHERE { 
        dbpedia:Nancy_Mairs dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract; dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?thumbnail .
    }
    LIMIT 1
```

If I miss the second condition out it returns a record

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

    SELECT *
    WHERE { 
        dbpedia:Nancy_Mairs dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract
    }
    LIMIT 1
```

Rather than say if the first returns nothing then run the second can I do it all in one go and return an empty thumbnail if there is none?

Comment: [`OPTIONAL`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#OptionalMatching)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand a bit on [Stanislav's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56443924/missing-value-in-sparql-due-to-where-clause#comment99481749_56443924), you can use the [`OPTIONAL`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#OptionalMatching) keyword to describe graph patterns that are... well... optional. If there is a solution to this pattern, it will be returned with the rest of the solution; otherwise, only the "mandatory" part of the pattern will be returned.

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
    dbpedia:Nancy_Mairs dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract
    OPTIONAL {
        dbpedia:Nancy_Mairs dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?thumbnail
    }
}
```

---

If you want to factor out the repetition of `dbpedia:Nancy_Mairs`, you can use the [`BIND`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#bind) keyword:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
    BIND(dbpedia:Nancy_Mairs AS ?topic)

    ?topic dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract
    OPTIONAL {
        ?topic dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?thumbnail
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but should be: BIND(dbpedia:Nancy_Mairs AS ?topic